# htaccess doesn't work with included ampersand

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I need to pass additional get variable, but it doesnt work with the ampersand.
Any ideas what im doing wrong? (last line)

First 3 lines work just fine.

```
RewriteRule ^forums forum.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^fc/([0-9]+) forum.php?fc=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ft/([0-9]+) forum.php?ft=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ft/([0-9]+)/(0-9]+) forum.php?ft=$1&e=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, which URL is not working, please do mention here, thank you.

Comment: last one doesnt work. first 3 works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your htaccess in following manner. You could reduce from 4 rules to 3 rules. You need to place anchors in regex to avoid false positive matches while uri matches in Rules.

Please make sure you are clearing your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^ft/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ forum.php?ft=$1&e=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(fc|ft)/([0-9]+)/?$ forum.php?$1=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^forums/?$ forum.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but still doest work with second variable. if (isset($_GET['e'])) { nothing happens }

Comment: @exclude1987, oh man, sorry there was a typo in Rules(I copied from yours and edited them), could you please do check my updated rules once? Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Let me know how it goes then.